# Hardness of maximizing difference of functions

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, proof-techniques

Suppose that the problem of maximizing a real function $f$ over a certain domain $D$ is NP_HARD. What can be said about the problem of maximizing $f-g$, with $g$ being another function over $D$? Is it possible to characterize $g$ in relation to $f$ in a way that can be assured that maximizing $f-g$ is also NP-HARD?

Comment: (I think the case where the $g$'s co-domain is "absorbent values only" (for subtraction, ±∞) special.)

Comment: @greybeard thank you for your comment. I am not sure I understand it, could you elaborate a little?

Comment: If $D$ contains some constant function, you're done. Same if $D$ is closed under multiplication by some positive constant different from $1$.

Comment: Note that if maximizing $f$ is hard, then so is maximizing $g = f - 1$. However, maximizing $f - g = 1$ is trivial.

Comment: @Watercrystal yes, that is the point. With some engineered functions it is clear that $f$ can be hard but $f-g$ easy, being $f=g$ the simplest example. But which is in general the relation between the two functions for that to happen?

Comment: Note that maximizing two easy to maximize functions can also be computationally hard. For instance, I could define f(0) and g(0) to be absurdly large values (diff is zero here) which are defined as maximums by construction. The remainder of the real domain could be split up to map to boolean variable assignments. I could take this convention and define the functions f and g to correspond to some hard counting or MAXSAT like problem (or worse, undecidable!). I suspect you need really carefully defined requirements for f and g (such as PTIME computable) so the question doesn't get out of hand.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/130144/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47582/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's not likely to be any characterization that is very useful.  The optimization problems can be hard or easy depending on $g$.

To give an analogy: you could ask for a characterization of functions $f$ for which it is NP-hard to maximize $f$.  Well, you're probably not going to find a useful one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It could very well be as you say. However, I feel that $f$ and $g$ must be in general connected somehow; if $f$ is hard and $f-g$ is easy, it seems that $g$ should have some specific structure that "removes complexity" from the problem, shouldn't it? For example, $g$ definition cannot allow the polynomial time computation of $max(f)$ from $max(f-g)$